# Do you need a special dvd burner to burn dual layer dvds?

Tags: dvd, burning

I have a DVD that I want to burn, but it's one of those huge dual layer ones. I'm wondering, before I attempt the burn process, if I need a special DVD burner in my PC to make this work properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install the freely available "VSO Inspector" software to determine whether your burner is capable of burning Dual-Layer DVDs [from this link.](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/inspector/inspector.php)

Comment: Worked a treat.

Comment: This also works for bluray drives.

Answer (score 9):

In order to burn a Dual-Layer DVD, your burner has to be able to adjust the optical laser used to write data to the disk in a way that allows it to bypass the first writeable layer and write data to the second layer. Dual-Layer DVD's have two writeable layers, and on any dual-layer capable drive I have ever seen, it's labeled as capable of writing Dual-Layer discs.

Look for something like this on your drive:

```
DVD+/-RW DL
DVD-R/RW DL
DVD+R/RW DL
DVD+RW DL
DVD-RW DL
```

Although most newer drives are 'multi' drives capable of writing both plus (+) and minus (-) DVDR/RW's, older drives may only be able to read/write one format, either plus or minus. Also, notice the `DL` on my list above. This stands for Dual-Layer.

If your drive has this `DL` label, it is dual-layer capable. Make sure you buy the right type of disc if your drive can only read one type and not the other, this is a common mistake since CD-R's only have one format (any CD-R/RW works in a CD-R/RW drive, but DVD's have two (DVD-R/RW and DVD+R/RW).

Answer (score 7):

You do. The drive has to be able to realign the write optics to focus on the second layer.

Comment: Most modern DVD writers support dual-layer, but older ones might not.